# The responsiblity of creation related entities

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, aggregation

I have an entity named "Task". For this entity I can create multiply entities, called "Comment". I want also to have a method named "CreateComment".  According to the Domain Driven Design, the entity "Comment" can not exist without creating an instance of "Task" class.   And my question is: where this method should be placed: in the Task class or in the Comment class? should it be like Comment.CreateComment or Task.CreateComment. If I put this method to the Task class, would it be the Single responsibility principle violation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the method should be be on the `Task` entity. But that being said the method should not be `Create` but rather `Add` as I do not believe it is a responsibility of the `Task` object to create a comment. Instead I'd use something like this, which is an overkill but mostly because I like a progress fluent interface and the object builder pattern :)

**Task class, pretty self explanatory**

```
public class Task
{
    private readonly IList<Comment> Comments = new List<Comment>();

    public void AddComment(ICommentBuilderFinalization commentBuilder)
    {
        Comments.Add(commentBuilder.MakeComment());
    }
}
```

**Comment class, pretty self explanatory once again**

```
public class Comment
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string PostedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedAt { get; set; }
}
```

**The object builder and progressive fluent interfaces**

```
// First progressive interface
public interface ICommentBuilder
{
    ICommentBuilderPostBy PostWasMadeNow();
    ICommentBuilderPostBy PostWasMadeSpecificallyAt(DateTime postedAt);
}

// Second progressive interface
public interface ICommentBuilderPostBy
{
    ICommentBuilderPostMessage By(string postedBy);
}

// Third progressive interfacve
public interface ICommentBuilderPostMessage
{
    ICommentBuilderFinalization About(string message);
}

// Final
public interface ICommentBuilderFinalization
{
    Comment MakeComment();
}

// implementation of the various interfaces
public class CommentBuilder : ICommentBuilder, ICommentBuilderPostBy, ICommentBuilderPostMessage, ICommentBuilderFinalization
{
    private Comment InnerComment = new Comment();

    public Comment MakeComment()
    {
        return InnerComment;
    }

    public ICommentBuilderFinalization About(string message)
    {
        InnerComment.Text = message;
        return this;
    }

    public ICommentBuilderPostMessage By(string postedBy)
    {
        InnerComment.PostedBy = postedBy;
        return this;
    }

    public ICommentBuilderPostBy PostWasMadeNow()
    {
        InnerComment.PostedAt = DateTime.Now;
        return this;
    }

    public ICommentBuilderPostBy PostWasMadeSpecificallyAt(DateTime postedAt)
    {
        InnerComment.PostedAt = postedAt;
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Putting it all together**

```
var task = new Task();
var commentBuilder = new CommentBuilder().PostWasMadeNow().By("Some User").About("Some Comment");

task.AddComment(commentBuilder);
```

Ok, so as I mentioned earlier this example is way over engineered for most situations. But it should give you an idea as to what you can do to stay true to the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: *"It is vain to do with more what can be done with fewer"* - William of Occam.

Answer (score 0):

According to [GRASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29), principles

> class B should be responsible for creating instances of class A if one, or preferably more, of the following apply:

- Instances of B contain or compositely aggregate instances of A
- Instances of B record instances of A
- Instances of B closely use instances of A
- Instances of B have the initializing information for instances of A and pass it on creation.

From your description it sounds like at least 3 of those points are pertinent. Therefore I would say that `Task` is responsible for creating `Comment`.